# Using Pandas resample after filtering out weekends

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm combining a few resample operations to get the average daily traffic after excluding weekends. In the last resampling for the year the zeroes are again part of the calculation. How do I get rid of them?

```
df5[df5.index.dayofweek < 5].qKfz_gesamt.resample('1h').mean().resample('1d') \   
    .sum().resample('1y').mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the parameter [`min_count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.sum.html) in the `sum` after the resampling per day. Then weekends are nan and don't affect the yearly resampling with `mean`:

```
(df5[df5.index.dayofweek < 5].qKfz_gesamt
    .resample('1h').mean()
    .resample('1d').sum(min_count=1) #here is the parameter
    .resample('1y').mean())
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! It worked perfectly. Thank you :)